# html 5- Videos - White is washed off in Chrome

Tags: html, video, google-chrome

Trying to get html5 videos working and running into a color problem.

(For those interested, there's [also this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847924/html-5-webm-conversion-output-has-green-area-on-the-right))

Chrome renders videos slightly differently than other browser.

On safari & firefox the background is nice and white. On chrome it's a washed off beige.

See compared screenshots:

[image]

It doesn't matter which codec is used - Chrome reads m4v, ogg and webm fine - but they all render washed off..

Can't seem to be able to correct this.

Any idea?

Comment: @knu. Yeah, that's what I thought but 1) there was no visible setting in Chrome for it. 2) It only affected videos, surround white background was properly white.. only the video tag area was affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's interesting.. seems to only happens on the latest dev version (10.0.648.6).

If I switch back to the current mainstream version (8.0.552.237) all the problems go away (including the cross-referenced question problem)

Comment: I think it's okay to accept your own answer, if that solves it for you.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc. Thanks. Waiting a few days to see if anyone can add some input to it..

Comment: Did you ever find another solution to this? I'm having this problem as well in Chrome 10.0.648.151.

Comment: @Mark. The official stable version was working fine so figured it was something in the dev version. Left it to that. Might be worth filing a bug before the problem become mainstream release (haven't had time for it though)