# embeding a video on a website without controls

Tags: html, video, google-chrome, embed

I am trying to embed a video on a website which will be used as an intro. Im interested in a way of embeding that video without a control bar (play,pause...). I can convert it to any format as I have the project file so compability isnt an issue. I have tried inserting it with  tag in HTML5 and that works seamlessly but because of a bug in Chrome white color in the video becomes gray and that doesnt work for me because video background has to be white so it can be camouflaged with the rest of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I haven't seen the Chrome/white issue, but from the sounds of it... it's just in dev versions of Chrome? I'm basing this off the last comment from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858424/html-5-videos-white-is-washed-off-in-chrome).

Looks like there was a patch, and it's waiting [to be merged](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73234&q=html5%20video%20colors&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS).

Not sure if these help in terms of using HTML5's video tag. If you don't care about the tag, you could always go with a Flash-based version using an .mp4 file. That way, whenever you're comfortable with Chrome's rendering... you could set it back up with the video tag.

Again, if you're ok with using Flash... you could pull it off like so (using [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)):

```
<object width="600" height="338" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://whywouldyouclickthat.com/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="http://whywouldyouclickthat.com/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "/yourDirectory/yourMovie.mp4", "autoPlay":true, "autoBuffering":true},"plugins": {"controls": null}}' />
</object>
```

Again, not sure if Flash is a deal-breaker here.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this, flash is not a dealbreaker I was just trying to use the simplicity of HTML5 video tag. And to answer to your question, believe it or not, it is a official Chrome version which anybody can download from [link](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome.html)